# Django messages.success don't work

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I create a message in my forms.py

```
def clean(self):
    request = self.request
    data = self.cleaned_data
    email  = data.get("email")
    password  = data.get("password")
    qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
    if qs.exists():
        # user email is registered, check active/
        not_active = qs.filter(is_active=False)
        if not_active.exists():
            ## not active, check email activation
            link = reverse("account:resend-activation")
            reconfirm_msg = """Go to <a href='{resend_link}'>
            resend confirmation email</a>.
            """.format(resend_link = link)
            confirm_email = EmailActivation.objects.filter(email=email)
            is_confirmable = confirm_email.confirmable().exists()
            if is_confirmable:
                msg1 = "Please check your email to confirm your account or " + reconfirm_msg.lower()
                raise forms.ValidationError(mark_safe(msg1))
            email_confirm_exists = EmailActivation.objects.email_exists(email).exists()
            if email_confirm_exists:
                msg2 = "Email not confirmed. " + reconfirm_msg
                raise forms.ValidationError(mark_safe(msg2))
            if not is_confirmable and not email_confirm_exists:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user is inactive.")
    user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
    if user is None:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid credentials")
    login(request, user)
    self.user = user
    return data
```

And when I use a simple html it works well and show the message in my screen:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Login</h1>
    <form method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
      <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

But when I use a more 'complex' html the message "Please check your email to confirm your account or " just do not appear:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Cadastro</title>

    <!-- Vendor css -->
    <link href="{% static 'lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'lib/Ionicons/css/ionicons.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Slim CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/slim.css' %}">

  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
    <form method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="signin-wrapper">

      <div class="signin-box">
        <h2 class="slim-logo"><a href="index.html">Site<span>.</span></a></h2>
        <h2 class="signin-title-primary">Bem vindo de volta!</h2>
        <h3 class="signin-title-secondary">Faça login para continuar.</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
          {{ form.email }}
        </div><!-- form-group -->
        <div class="form-group mg-b-50">
          {{ form.password }}
        </div><!-- form-group -->
        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-signin">Entrar</button>
        <p class="mg-b-0"><a href="{% url "password_change" %}">Esqueci minha senha</a></p>
        <p class="mg-b-0">Não tem conta? <a href="../cadastro">Faça um cadastro</a></p>
      </div><!-- signin-box -->

    </div><!-- signin-wrapper -->
    </form>

    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I already debug and see the message is being properly created, But it do not appear.
Someone have any idea why?

Comment: to access validation errors in templates `form.field_name.errors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All form validations errors are here in `form.errors` which is a dictionary.
More info can be found in the [Official Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors)

Make sure that form.erros is `not None`

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field, errors in form.errors.items %}
        {{ errors }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

to access separate field errors, you need the following: `form.field_name.errors`.

```
{{ form.password }}
{%  if form.password.arrors %}
    {{ form.password.errors }} <!-- {{ form.password.errors.as_text }} -->
{% endif %}
```